# FullCalendar events is displayed in days of the month view incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

This is the scenario, if i add an event, with the date range of ff:

start date is: 2018-03-25 and start time is 8:00 AM

end date is:   2018-03-27 and end time is   **9:00 AM**

The event displayed correctly right in the day of the calendar. But when i change the time of the end date into **8:00 AM**, the event display -1 day in the calendar.

I'm having dificulty in analyzing the problem, that they were the same in date, only differs in time. I'm suspecting that the problem is in timezone.

So i add the GMT in each date of the event, then i got this **"GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard)"** because i'm in Asia,

Then i checked the date timezone in my Computer that i'm using and changed it to the same timezone **"GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard)"**

But still the porblem exist. Please help me. Where could be the problem is?

[SAMPLE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cAyz.png)

Comment: It's because of this option: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold . This question has been asked many times before on StackOverflow already - did you search?

Comment: I have been searching for it till now. But unfortunately i couldn't find the right answer for it. :( Can i disable that option? @ADyson

Comment: No but you can change it to another value which works better for you

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, it actually works. i set the nextDayThreshold into "00:00:00" and  the event is now in the correct day. Thank you.